# ¿Como realizar un inner join de forma más rápida sin depender del id?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Buen día comunidad, espero que se encuentren bien, y si me pueden ayudar a averiguar como resolver un asunto de un query.

Estoy tratando de hacer un UPDATE en MYSQL(phpMyAdmin) con inner join de una tabla a otra por medio de un campo en comun (un "codigo") no es el id, como lo tengo ligado a un sistema donde se dan de alta registros, no puedo relacionarlos por esa llave, lo tengo por ese otro codigo.

Estuve investigando y llegue a este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709043/mysql-update-column-with-value-from-another-table

Las consultas que probe si me funcionaron, pero se tarda mucho, más de 35min (en hacer el update de 55000 registros), anteriormente había tenido el mismo problema pero lo solucione haciendolo por medio del id, pero en este caso no puedo usar esa columna.

y quise probar esta otra consulta

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ACTUALIZACION;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ACTUALIZACION()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE clave_mct2 TEXT DEFAULT '';
DECLARE precio_mct2 TEXT DEFAULT '';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM master_ct2 INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
SELECT clave, MEJOR_PRECIO FROM master_ct2 limit i,1 INTO clave_mct2, precio_mct2;
UPDATE productos SET precio_compra=precio_mct2 where codigo=clave_mct2;
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END$$;
DELIMITER ;
```

pero no pude hacerla correr, me tira este error

[*Warning: #1287 ' INTO ;' está desaprobado, use ''SELECT  INTO  FROM...'' en su lugar*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCOmn.png)

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea para darle solución?, estuve leyendo acerca de tablas temporales, luego de ahi pasar los datos por otro inner join.

El tema principal es que este query si me funciona

```
UPDATE productos
INNER JOIN master_ct2 ON productos.codigo = master_ct2.clave
SET productos.precio_compra = IF(master_ct2.MEJOR_PRECIO > 0, master_ct2.MEJOR_PRECIO, productos.precio_compra)
WHERE master_ct2.id < 55000
```

pero se tarda más de 30min en terminar de procesarse.
Muchas gracias a todos de antemano y por pasarse por el post.
¡Saludos!

Comment: Y en ambas tablas el respectivo campo (código y clave) tienen índice?

Comment: Holaa, gracias por responder, si, ambas tablas tienen su id
id | clave para master_ct2
id | codigo para productos

pero lo complicado es que los ids no los puedo tomar como el referente porque se eliminan y dan de alta productos, cambian y no tienen relacion uno con el otro, así que por eso tomo el codigo/clave que es el mismo en las 2 tablas, aunque se eliminen filas

Comment: Se entiende lo del ID. Pregunto si los campos del código tienen índice (no he dicho que sea llave única)

Answer (score 1):

Encontre tu fallo de sintaxis.

Tu tienes lo siguientes :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ACTUALIZACION;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ACTUALIZACION()
BEGIN
     DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE clave_mct2 TEXT DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE precio_mct2 TEXT DEFAULT '';
     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM master_ct2 INTO n;
     SET i=0;
     WHILE i<n DO 
          SELECT clave, MEJOR_PRECIO FROM master_ct2 limit i,1 INTO clave_mct2, 
          precio_mct2;
          UPDATE productos SET precio_compra=precio_mct2 where codigo=clave_mct2;
          SET i = i + 1;
     END WHILE;
END$$;
DELIMITER ;
```

Si te das cuenta `SELECT clave, MEJOR_PRECIO FROM master_ct2 limit i,1 INTO clave_mct2,precio_mct2;` el into ese esta mal tendria que ser asi `SELECT clave, MEJOR_PRECIO INTO clave_mct2, precio_mct2 FROM master_ct2 limit i,1;`

Por lo que se quedaria de la siguiente manera.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ACTUALIZACION;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ACTUALIZACION()
BEGIN
     DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE clave_mct2 TEXT DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE precio_mct2 TEXT DEFAULT '';
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM master_ct2;
     SET i=0;
     WHILE i<n DO 
          SELECT clave, MEJOR_PRECIO INTO clave_mct2,precio_mct2 FROM master_ct2 limit i,1;
          UPDATE productos SET precio_compra=precio_mct2 where codigo=clave_mct2;
          SET i = i + 1;
     END WHILE;
END $$;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Si es correcto no te olvides de marcarlas